# VB.NET Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow using FileStream

Tags: vb.net, filestream

I'm trying to copy files from a directory to another using the `FileStream` and it works fine, but when copying large files it throws me an error `Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.` It cannot copy a file larger than 20MB. Please I'm new to programming can you help me with this?

```
Private mCurrentFile As String = String.Empty

Public ReadOnly Property CurrentFile() As String
    Get
        Return mCurrentFile
    End Get
End Property

Dim FS As FileStream
    mCurrentFile = GetFileName(URL)
    Dim wRemote As WebRequest
    Dim bBuffer As Byte()
    ReDim bBuffer(256)
    Dim iBytesRead As Integer
    Dim iTotalBytesRead As Integer

    FS = New FileStream(Location, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    wRemote = WebRequest.Create(URL)
    Dim myWebResponse As WebResponse = wRemote.GetResponse
    RaiseEvent FileDownloadSizeObtained(myWebResponse.ContentLength)
    Dim sChunks As Stream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream
    Do
        iBytesRead = sChunks.Read(bBuffer, 0, 256)

        FS.Write(bBuffer, 0, iBytesRead)
        iTotalBytesRead += iBytesRead
        If myWebResponse.ContentLength < iTotalBytesRead Then
            RaiseEvent AmountDownloadedChanged(myWebResponse.ContentLength)
        Else
            RaiseEvent AmountDownloadedChanged(iTotalBytesRead)
        End If
    Loop While Not iBytesRead = 0 And dStop = False
    sChunks.Close()
    FS.Close()

Private Sub _Downloader_FileDownloadSizeObtained(ByVal iFileSize As Long) Handles _Downloader.FileDownloadSizeObtained
    'FIRES WHEN WE HAVE GOTTEN THE DOWNLOAD SIZE, SO WE KNOW WHAT BOUNDS TO GIVE THE PROGRESS BAR
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = CInt(iFileSize)
End Sub
```

The error throws here.

```
Private Sub _Downloader_AmountDownloadedChanged(ByVal iNewProgress As Long) Handles _Downloader.AmountDownloadedChanged
    'FIRES WHEN MORE OF THE FILE HAS BEEN DOWNLOADED
    ProgressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt64(iNewProgress)  '<-------------- Error throws here
    Application.DoEvents()
End Sub
```

I don't know any more larger type that can handle large files or is there any other way?

Comment: Firstly, why are you passing a `Long` to `Convert.ToInt64`?  It's already an `Int64`.  That's what a `Long` is.  As for the exception, what type is `UserControl12.Value`?  I'm guessing that it's `Integer`, i.e. `Int32`.  That means that, if your `Long` contains a value larger the `Int32.MaxValue` then trying to force it into an `Int32` will cause an overflow, i.e. there will be too much data to fit.

Comment: It would appear that you have `Option Strict Off` or that code wouldn't even compile, as it would refuse to let you try to put a `Long` value into a `Integer` property.  You should turn `Option Strict On` for this project and every other project you work on.  It won't fix issues like this but it will alert you to the fact that they are there.

Comment: If you're trying to display progress when the values are `Long` then the best option is to use the two `Long` values to calculate a percentage and then use that as your progress instead of absolute values.

Comment: Finally, `UserControl12` is an incredibly bad name for anything.  You should fix your naming conventions.

Comment: Sorry. please look at my updated code, that's a `ProgressBar`

Comment: Then the issue is EXACTLY as I have already stated, so why haven't you already fixed it instead of asking me to look again?

Comment: Dial in Option Strict and rip off the knob.

Comment: Sorry im just new to programming, still figuring out how to do what you have said.

Comment: Project Properties -> Compile Tab;  To make it your default always (recommended): Tools -> Options - > Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults

Comment: @jmcilhinney you said using two `Long` values is the best option, The first `Long` is the size of the file right? but what would be the other one?

Comment: `...when the values are Long` in the case of the ProgressBar's value property, it isnt.  Unless you know the size so you can calculate a Percent completed, which you apparently do not, just set it to marquee to show the user Stuff Is Happening.

Comment: "The first Long is the size of the file right? but what would be the other one?"  It would be the amount read so far.  What else could it be if the point of the progress is to show what proportion of the total has been completed so far?  If the maximum value was within the range of type `Integer` then you could set the `Maximum` of the `ProgressBar` to the total size and the `Value` to the amount read but, if the maximum is too big for `Integer` then working with percentages is the best bet.  If you can't actually calculate a proportion then do as @Plutonix has suggested.